# How to ingest my log files (which are generated in my EC2 instance) into azure data cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-ec2, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I'm trying to ingest my log files which are generated in the Ec2 instance (API Logs) into the Azure cloud. Which service i need to select in azure?. Please help me out to find the solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to export these logs to an S3 bucket then you can use Azure Data Factory to pull logs from this bucket to Azure blob or data lake.

Comment: If this has helped you unblock this situation, great if you can make this an answer which will be helpful for others facing the similar challenge